# root undoing previous changes after sudo su user

Tags: zsh, sudo, su, zshrc, subshell

I am having a hard time with `root`

whenever i run `sudo su` and then `nano ~/.zshrc`, edit my file to add PATHs followed by a `source ~/.zshrc`, it works just fine.

That until i run `sudo su myuser` to go back to my default user.

When i do that all my previous settings on `root` are undone, and if i go back and check `~/.zshrc` it has no PATHs configured and doesnt work as intented.

Does anyone know why this happens? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having, is that `~` resolves to the home directory for the current user. So when logged in as root, `~` points to *root*'s home directory (usually at `/root`), whereas for *myuser*, `~` points at *myuser*'s home directory (usually `/home/myuser`), so you're actually editing different files.